# What is meaning of "up the block"?

Tags: phrases

What does phrase "we're up the block" mean? And specifically word block.

> Now it's two o'clock
>   The club is closed and we're up the block

Comment: A "block" is a rectangle surrounded on 4 sides by streets.  "Up the block" merely means that the individual has left the "club" and walked along the sidewalk a modest distance.  (Whether it's "up" or "down" is an entirely different discussion.)

Comment: so, can it be understood as 'we're going through the street'?

Comment: Well, perhaps.  If I knew what "going through the street" meant.

Comment: walking through the street. 
(I'm not english native speaker)

Comment: "Up the block" in this case means "down the block" . . .

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that Robusto.
Does "block" = "street" or does it not?

Comment: Well, one usually stays out of the street (except that it might be OK at 2AM, if the drunk drivers aren't too thick).  But the image is of walking along the sidewalk between street and buildings, "window shopping" and otherwise "seeing the sights" (and, depending on the individuals, groping each other).

Comment: What is the context? Is this a text you received from someone you're supposed to meet? Or is this from a novel/play/TV with an expectation of something happening afterwards? Maybe they don't have a ride? Is this American English or British English (or some other)?

Comment: "Block" does not mean "street", but, as I said earlier, a "block" is a rectangular area surrounded on all sides by streets.  (A "street" is where cars drive.  A "sidewalk" is the pedestrian walking space between street and the buildings facing the street.)

Comment: yes, but this is song lyrics I wanna translate, and I can't be extensive, therefore I must use some poetic freedom, but hit the right meaning of the word.   @Mitch it's lyrics definitely with an expectation of something happening afterwards.

Comment: Sandoken, unfortunately anything goes in song lyrics so it could be they made it up for the song. It sounds weird to me, an AmE speaker. Is it maybe British?

Comment: @Mitch - "The club is closed and we're up the block" is perfectly fine idiomatic US English.

Comment: @HotLicks Ok. It's not idiomatic for my AmE idiolect. Like Robusto implied, 'down the block' is what would be natural for me and 'up the block' I would still think is weird (It makes me think 'up the creek', like the bar closed and it's the middle of the night and there's no ride home).

Comment: @Mitch - You never heard "up the street" or "up the road"?

Comment: @HotLicks: 'up the road a bit' yes. 'up the street' no, but it sounds reasonable. 'up the block' sounds strange to me. The only place I can imagine this feeling right would be San Francisco.

Comment: @Mitch - You've led a sheltered life.

Comment: I'm from NYC and navigation here is mostly numerical (at least north of the village which is the oldest and most organic/least planned part of town). We use both *up the block* and *down the block*; *up* means *up*, numerically, which corresponds roughly to "north" (81st st is one block north[-ish] of 80th st).

Answer (score 1):

These lyrics could be rewritten in a less poetic way:

> The time is now 2 o'clock. The club is closed. We are not in the club; we are further down the street and have not yet crossed an intersection.

A *street* is made of *blocks*. To be *up the block* is to be a distance along the street, but within the same block.

---

**Side note**:
Depending on the context within the song, this particular lyric may also be skipping an intended *heading*, which would give you the impression that the band is in motion during this stanza rather than having already moved to the location up the block.

> The club is closed and we're *heading* up the block.