# What exactly does "it's down the street" mean?

Tags: meaning

When giving addresses, what exactly is the meaning of "it's down the street" ?

> 1. Go straight along the street and it's a little further.
> 2. It's at the end of the street.
> 3. It's somewhere in the end.

Comment: It could mean pretty much anything, but usually would mean within a few blocks.  "Down the road" would go even further afield.

Comment: See also http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/233085/what-is-meaning-of-up-the-block

Answer (score 1):

*[Down the street](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/down_2)* means it is somewhere along the street, towards the direction you are facing.